# RESTful api: accessing objects (Mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having trouble getting data that is input in a URL most especially when the data being accessed is an object.

Example URL:

- localhost:9000?building=Salesforce&city=San Francisco&date=January 10
- localhost:9000?grade=A
- localhost:9000?subject=Science

Sample data:

```
{
  Name: "Andrew"
  address: Object
    building: "Salesforce"
    city: "San Francisco"
  grades: Object
    0: Object
       date: 2020-1-30T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "A" 
       subject: "Science"
    1: Object 
       date: 2020-1-28T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "C"
       subject: "Math"
    2: Object
       date: 2020-2-28T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "B"
       subject: "Chemistry"
}, {
  Name: "Steven"
  address: Object
    building: "Empire State Building"
    city: "New York"
  grades: Object
    0: Object
       date: 2020-1-30T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "B" 
       subject: "Computer Science"
    1: Object 
       date: 2020-1-28T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "A"
       subject: "Math"
    2: Object
       date: 2020-2-28T00:00:00.000+00:00
       grade: "C"
       subject: "History"
}
```

What would be a good query to return the correct data of the APIs above using mongoose?

Also, how would I get the unique values with distinct() for

- building
- city
- date
- grade
- subject